# Run StreamListener (Tweepy) and analyze tweets simultaneously

Tags: python, twitter, stream, tweepy

I am currently using Tweepy to stream tweets and am outputting each tweet in a json file. Once I am done listening and close the stream, I am analyzing the tweets for sentiment. I was wondering if there was a way to do this simultaneously. I want to start the stream, output the tweet in the json file, then run my sentiment analysis on that tweet and then do it again and again for each individual tweet in real time.

```
def on_status(self, status):
    self.output.write(status + "\n")

    self.counter += 1

    if self.counter >= 20000:

        self.output.close()
        self.output = open('../streaming_data/' + self.fprefix + '.' + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.json', 'w')
```

Above is my is my stream listener. The output file is self.output.

```
tweets = {}

with open(output.json, 'r') as file:
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in file)
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)

    for line in lines:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets[tweet['id']]= tweet
```

Above is how I'm storing each tweet in tweets so that I can analyze them using a function. My function takes tweets as an argument.

```
function = myFunction(tweets, pos, neg)
```

Essentially StreamListener collects tweets and stores them in a json file. But I want to collect tweets and analyze them as soon as I get them. So collect one tweet, then analyze it, then do it again.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any specific reason as to why you are storing the tweet as a json file? Why not simply store the tweet text as a text file, since I assume you are only preforming analysis on the text of the tweet. Also, why not call a function to process the tweet and have it write to the file at the same time?

Might look something like the following:

```
import tweepy
import secrets


class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        process_tweet(status.text)


def process_tweet(tweet):
    with open('tweets.txt', 'w') as tweet_file:
        tweet_file.write(tweet)
        sentiment_analysis(tweet)


def sentiment_analysis(tweet):
    #code to determine the sentiment of a tweet
```

You should use the async parameter to execute the stream in another thread :

```
aStream.filter(track=[aFilter], async=True)
```

or

```
aStream.userstream(async=True)
```